# Get directions in map in swift 3

Tags: ios, mkmapview, swift3

I wanna get directions from my own location to pre-defined location. I can do it by opening it in browser but it needs to be done in application only. Is there a way to draw route and update it as current location changes?

I am using following code which opens in browser. I want it to remain in the application only

```
let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=\(lat),\(long)&daddr=\(latgest),\(longgest)&dirflg=d")!

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
else
{
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's say the place you are is the "source" and you want to go to your "destination". Try this:

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapview.delegate = self

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.203314, longitude: -8.410257), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.112808, longitude: -8.498689), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    request.transportType = .walking

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

        for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
            self.mapview.add(route.polyline)
            self.mapview.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        }
    } 
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        polylineRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.red
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2
        return polylineRenderer


    }

}
```

Don't forget to Outlet the mapview.
This worked for me.
Let us know if it worked for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded map framework you are looking for is called MapKit and it supports routing.  There are many tutorials for it, such as https://www.raywenderlich.com/110054/routing-mapkit-core-location

Comment: Thanks for reply but this shows me poly line, i want direction in real time tracking like if current location moves forward to that address it shows turn this way and give direction .